# Add the factors of a number user inputs

Tags: java

I am trying to add all of the factors of a number that the user provides. For example, if the user inputs 5, the output should be : "The sum of the factors of 5 is 6."
I cannot figure out how to do add these numbers. Here is what I have tried:

```
int i = 1;
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(i <= num) 
{
   sum = i + 1;
   if(num % i == 0)
   {
       System.out.println(i + " is a factor of "+num+".");
       count++;
   }

    i++;
}  

 System.out.println(num+" has "+count+" factors.");
 System.out.println("The sum of all of the factors of "+num+" is "+sum);
```

Comment: Good job posting what you have tried so far. You were close. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic bug in your code. You're basically resetting the sum each time through the loop, rather than cumulatively adding the factors together to give you a running total. So in the last iteration of the loop, you'll get whatever the last number checked was, plus one. To fix the bug, remove this line:

```
sum = i + 1;
```

And add this line inside the `if` condition:

```
sum += i;
```

The code should look like this:

```
int i = 1;
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(i <= num) 
{
   if(num % i == 0)
   {
       System.out.println(i + " is a factor of "+num+".");
       count++;
       sum += i;
   }
   i++;
}  

System.out.println(num+" has "+count+" factors.");
System.out.println("The sum of all of the factors of "+num+" is "+sum);
```

I've just verified the output for `n=5` is:

```
1 is a factor of 5.
5 is a factor of 5.
5 has 2 factors.
The sum of all of the factors of 5 is 6
```

But 5 is prime. Here is a more interesting example with more factors: `n=8`:

```
1 is a factor of 8.
2 is a factor of 8.
4 is a factor of 8.
8 is a factor of 8.
8 has 4 factors.
The sum of all of the factors of 8 is 15
```

Note: your algorithm can be optimized. Hint: when you find a factor, you can easily determine another one by dividing your input number by it. I leave the rest of the optimization to you as an exercise. Enjoy!